Switching between different loads on C.C. LED power supply
I'm designing a visual system with many different lamps. It's my first time working with LED power supply. I want to use one constant current LED power supply for a couple of 24 V DC LED lamps (floodlights, “halogens”). Supply rated power is 240 W, lamps vary from 120 W to 200 W. At any given moment only one lamp or none will be lit. Current needs to be adjusted individually so as to not damage the lamps.
My approach is to keep the LED power supply on (to get inrush current only once, upon startup) and connect loads via relay contacts.
LED power supply has a 3 in 1 dimming functions: 1-10 V, 10 V PWM, and resistance.
For the resistance option, output current is proportional to resistance connected (100 kΩ is 100%, open is 100%). This requires additional 2 contacts per relay. Here's a sketch to give you an idea. Note that there will be 5 lamps.

Instead, I could use an MCU that outputs PWM with duty cycle based on active relay (K1, K2... as digital inputs). I would introduce a delay between switching loads — when no relays are active, set PWM to lowest required current — 50% in this case.
Is there anything I'm missing with my approach? Perhaps there's a simpler solution, maybe without using the dimmer.
Can disconnecting the load from the LED power supply whilst in constant current mode damage it?
Edit: Manual states short circuit protection works in hiccup mode. Thus I can safely disconnect load.

We don't know which model LED supply you have and if it can damage when load is suddenly disconnected. Please see the data sheet or manual of the supply what protections it has.

@Justme manual provided me with an answer
